# How can I assign actions to all my mouse buttons?

Tags: mouse

I have a mouse with lots of buttons, but it's not a mainstream make like Logitech. For Windows, I have a driver that lets me assign actions like close-window (Ctrl+W) or next-tab (Ctrl+Tab), but I don't have a Linux driver. Since Linux is so flexible, I thought perhaps there is a general way to do this, regardless of brand?

**Update:** Based on input from Cyrex, I installed and ran `sudo apt-get install btnx` which found several but not all mouse buttons.
Found: left, right, wheel, wheelclick, thumb fwd, thumb back.
**Not found:** wheel left, wheel right, thumb middle button.
Vendor ID is 0x04d9, Model ID is 0xa015.

**Update 2:** In System>Prefs>Mouse there's a lightbulb icon for testing double-click speed. Every working button can turn the bulb on&off, but the missing buttons can't. **It would seem that Ubuntu isn't aware of these buttons and thus doesn't register their clicks.** I guess I need to hunt for a driver, though a mainstream mouse is probably the easier way.

Comment: Please explain what mouse button 9 is.

Comment: @mateo_salta Got that in seconds before me.

Comment: Do you use Unity?

Comment: What make and model is it?

Comment: @int_ua Yes, I strive use a system configuration as close to the default as I can tolerate.

Comment: @acematrix It's a Logitech M705. The number assignments in the image correspond with those used in [CCSM](http://askubuntu.com/questions/80589/what-are-some-of-the-issues-with-ccsm-and-why-should-i-not-use-it) bindings.

Comment: Have you read [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1694352.html)?

Comment: @penreturn Post that bit about easystroke instant gestures as an answer and I might just accept it...

Comment: @BrunoPereira I was really hoping for a general solution that would work on other mice, as well.

Comment: @ændrük thing is, either we stick with some models and solutions, or we just close this one and migrate it all to the already existing posts. I'm ok with both, let me know what you want.

Comment: @ændrük ofc, it will be done

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If all buttons are detected correctly then you can install btnx:

`sudo apt-get install btnx` OR `sudo aptitude install btnx`

Then go to: **Applications -> System Tools -> Btnx**

It has support for many types of mice

Comment: I tested my mouse with btnx but it didn't recognize all my buttons. Does this indicate a problem with my mouse (driver?) or with btnx (unlikely I guess)?

Comment: Am guessing between. Maybe the mouse module is not detecting the mouse correctly so btnx does not either. Can you actually click all the buttons and see if a programa recognizes them, like the click test in the mouse settings.

Comment: I'm selecting this as the correct answer because *btnx* allows me to instantly test each mouse button - this proved that Ubuntu simply isn't aware of the extra buttons. I need to get a linux-friendly mouse.

Comment: btnx can not be found - has the package changed name?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/425246/where-can-i-find-btnx

Comment: **see [my answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1147753/943568) for updated version**

Answer (score 39):

I have a MX Anywhere "M-R0001"

I use my forward and Back buttons as Copy and Paste.

Steps:
1) All buttons are detected with last kernel... at least with

```
uname -a

3.8.0-25-generic #37-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 6 20:47:07 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

2) So, basically, you only need to map those buttons with desired actions. How to know with button is pressed and the correspondent numeric code? Well, you can use the 'xev' program:

```
xev
```

This program is a key and mouse events sniffer. When it's running, you can see a window in which you can press mouse buttons and see if they are detected. For example, with the zoom button of the Performance MX you will see something like that:

```
ButtonPress event, serial 35, synthetic NO, window 0x5800001,
    root 0x15a, subw 0x0, time 64521438, (84,117), root88,144),
    state 0x10, button 13, same_screen YES
```

that means that 13 is the code for that mouse button. You can try every mouse buttons on your hand  ... for easy access, here is the map for Performance MX:

- Back button: 8
- Forward button: 9
- Zoom button: 13
- Show windows button: 10

the other buttons are well recognized and you don't need to map to actions.

3) Now, you need to install a little program to re-map mouse and keyboard inputs. The magician is 'xbindkeys' ... the easy installation is using:

```
sudo apt-get install xbindkeys
```

4) Once installed, you can do the magic. The idea is configure the mouse buttons to send key combinations to activate other desktop functionalities (as the matter of fact, xbindkeys can be used for execute any other program when you press a mouse button). In KDE you can do that with Ctrl+F10 keys combination. The point is create a xbindkeys' configuration file to do the job.

5) To create the configuration file, just run the following command:

```
xbindkeys --defaults > $HOME/.xbindkeysrc
```

6) And we need to edit the file to specify your button's mapping:

```
gedit $HOME/.xbindkeysrc
```

7) We need to add our button-to-key configurations. For example, I have the following:

```
# Back changed to Copy
"xte 'keydown Control_L' 'key C' 'keyup Control_L'"
  b:8

# Forward
"xte 'keydown Alt_L' 'key Right' 'keyup Alt_L'"
  b:9

# Present desktops
"xte 'keydown Control_L' 'key F8' 'keyup Control_L'"
  b:13

# Present windows
"xte 'keydown Control_L' 'key F10' 'keyup Control_L'"
  b:10
```

8) There was a new requirement. the 'xte' program, which basically simulates user key press combinations. Install it using:

```
sudo apt-get install xautomation
```

Now, if you run on a terminal something like:

```
xte 'keydown Control_L' 'key F10' 'keyup Control_L'
```

that means simulate a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> keypress. The idea is using xbindkeys to say: "when I press 13th mouse button, send a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> keyboard press using xte program to generate that"

9) And finally, you need to configure 'xbindkeys' to run automatically on system startup. Startup Applications / Add program button and type '/usr/bin/xbindkeys' on the dialog.

DONE

Comment: Also, as a note, it's usually easier to grep xev with `xev | grep button` for mouse buttons..

Comment: Works great for me, except I didn't have to write a script to make it start with my computer for some reason. Thanks!

Comment: How would I go about making a mouse button so it acts like a different mouse button? This seems to be for keys in particular. For instance, I want button 8 to act like pressing the mousewheel button. Is that possible with xte?

Comment: @Brōtsyorfuzthrāx I believe you can. If you take a look at `man xte` you can see that there's a `mouseclick` action available. You can use it in the configuration file the same way you use `keydown` or `keyup`. Just give it the desired mouse button number.

Answer (score 11):

[image]

[**Easystroke**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/easystroke) is a Mouse gesture-recognition application and mouse gesture manager for Ubuntu and Other Linux distribution. it allows user to control ubuntu application with hand drawn mouse gestures or Draw on the Screen.  Easystroke work on Tablet PCs, it can be used equally well with a mouse, pen, or even your fingers if you have a touch-sensitive screen.

**Install Easystroke in Ubuntu**

```
sudo apt-get install easystroke
```

If you want installing easystroke via PPA, you can adding a PPA repository, type this command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:easystroke/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install easystroke
```

**For Unity Users** : EasyStroke have not used indicator applet yet, so when you run it from menu, you have nothing on Indicator Applet. To solve this problem, simply run these command in terminal:

```
easystroke -g
```

It will run EasyStroke and open configuration windows automatically.

**[Source](http://ubuntuportal.com/2012/04/easystroke-easy-tool-to-control-ubuntu-desktop-with-mouse-gestures.html)**

Comment: Didn't recognize the extra buttons on the Logitech G700s.

Answer (score 7):

[Easystroke Gesture Recognition](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/easystroke/) is designed primarily for creating custom [pointing device gestures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointing_device_gesture), but it can also be used to assign actions to simple button presses.

To use it in this manner,

1. [Open the configuration window](https://askubuntu.com/questions/201120/how-can-i-access-the-configuration-window-for-easystroke-gesture-recognition).
2. In **Preferences ▸ Behavior ▸ Additional Buttons ▸ Add**, select **Instant Gestures** and then press the desired mouse button in the gray box.

   [image: Easystroke Gesture Recognition - Select a Mouse or Pen Button]
3. In **Actions**, click **Add Action**.
4. Double-click in the **Stoke** column and then press the desired mouse button again.
5. Click in the **Name**, **Type** and **Details** columns to set up an action.

   [image: Easystroke Gesture Recognition - Actions]

Comment: The button registers in step 2, but nothing happens in step 4 when pressing it again.

Comment: "NOTE: As for now, easystroke is in an unmaintained state."

Answer (score 5):

If you install the [CompizConfig Settings Manager](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/compizconfig-settings-manager) [image: Install CompizConfig Settings Manager] then you will be able to set a lot of window management mouse button shortcuts.

It may take some effort working out which button is which.

In the screenshot I am assigning opening the Super+Tab switcher to a left-click of my scroll wheel.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

Olli Salonen has his own ppa which needs to be added to your list if you want to install via apt. Here is the info about adding ppa.

https://launchpad.net/~daou/+archive/ppa

Also, this [link](http://awesomelinux.blogspot.com/2012/08/btnx-for-ubuntu-1204-precise.html) might help with installing on newer version of Ubuntu since I see Olli isn't active for quite a while now.

Comment: and yes this link you provided is what I was looking for, thanks again

http://awesomelinux.blogspot.com/2012/08/btnx-for-ubuntu-1204-precise.html

Answer (score 2):

Source is here: http://github.com/cdobrich/btnx.git
It built and ran on my Linux Mint 13 without problems.  Caveat: btnx-config needs to be run with root perms.

Comment: I tried this and thought it didn't work.. My caveat was that I didn't know that btnx-config is a dependency from a different repository which also needs to be installed. So also this: https://github.com/cdobrich/btnx-config

Comment: However, the program is useless to me, I just wanted to be able to create a simlink or choose with a menu what to do after dragging a file/folder

Answer (score 1):

Btnx is available for download from [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/btnx-config/0.4.9-4ubuntu1).

Answer (score 1):

In mid-2017, there doesn't seem to be any updated *btnx* package for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, and *easystroke* also doesn't seem to be maintained any longer.

I wanted to assign copy / paste to the two additional buttons of my (decades-old, but battle-tested) *Microsoft IntelliMouse*, and finally settled on *imwheel*, which is described in [this page in the Ubuntu Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ManyButtonsMouseHowto).

For reference, here's my `~/.imwheelrc`:

```
# https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ManyButtonsMouseHowto

"^(Gnome-terminal|Tilda)"
None, Thumb1, Shift_L|Control_L|C
None, Thumb2, Shift_L|Control_L|Insert

".*"
None, Thumb1, Control_L|C
None, Thumb2, Control_L|V

# vim:ts=4:shiftwidth=4:syntax=sh
```

To start the tool together with the X server, set `IMWHEEL_START=1` in `/etc/X11/imwheel/startup.conf`.

Answer (score 1):

## Accepted answer is outdated, here is the updated version.

You should already have these as they should come with Ubuntu, but run this just in case.

```
sudo apt-get install libdaemon-dev libglade2-dev libgtk2.0-dev
```

Now, download & install

1) [btnx-config](https://github.com/cdobrich/btnx-config)
2) [btnx](https://github.com/cdobrich/btnx) In this order.

To install:

Unzip, and `cd` into each of these folders.

In each of them run:

```
./configure make
sudo make
sudo make install
```

Once both of them are installed, run

```
sudo btnx-config
```

In Configurations tab, click Detect Mouse & Buttons

[image]

In Buttons tab, assign your mouse button a key or functionality. **Make sure you ☑ check mark enabled**.

[image]

Lastly, in Configurations tab, click on Restart btx button so your changes take effect.

[image]

Comment: first i downloaded btnx-config and unzipped it. Then `./configure make` i get this as last **configure: error: /bin/bash config/config.sub make failed** and then when i try `sudo make` it says **make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.**

Comment: Compiling doesn't work on Ubuntu 19.10. I got the same error. I had to compile it on Ubuntu 18.04 and then install it on 19.10.

Comment: On Devuan ASCii I have the same error as @Larry. Any solution? Is there a btnx-PPA that works with Devuan ASCii or Lubuntu-QT 20.04?

Comment: @No Sssweat @Larry The command `./configure make` is wrong. **README** says `./configure` `make` `sudo make install` (and `sudo make uninstall` for uninstalling).

Answer (score 0):

On modern Ubuntu releases, [`input-remapper`](https://github.com/sezanzeb/input-remapper) provides a GUI and I think would suit this goal. See [How to access extra mouse buttons on Wayland?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1334432/how-to-access-extra-mouse-buttons-on-wayland)