# Lower mouse sensitivity below minimum?

Tags: 14.04, mouse, games

I have a gaming mouse and it's way too high sensitivity in Ubuntu compared to Windows.

The output of `xinput list` gives me:

`Virtual core pointer                        id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SteelSeries Rival Gaming Mouse            id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SteelSeries Rival Gaming Mouse            id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]`

How would I go about lowering the sensitivity even further? Any other options I should consider with a gaming mouse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the answer, but not sure how to make it permanent(I think it resets on reboot?)

First, do the above `xinput list` and get the id of your device. Not sure why, but there are 2 mice coming up with id=8 and id=10. I picked 8, and it worked.

I ran the following line `xinput --set-prop "8" "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" 1.5`, with the value of 1.5 being just tested and I found it pretty nice. Depends on mouse, so test different values etc.

However I guess you should create a bash script for this for it to work on startup. Not sure how to do so, but will figure it out I guess.

Comment: I bet [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/633331/expand-mouse-wheel-volume-control-to-whole-panel) could help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough rep to comment unfortunately, you simply open the startup applications app and add the command as /usr/bin/xinput  --set-prop "8" "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" 1.5. Then, at login the script will be run.