# How can I assign a custom command to a Logitech M705 mouse button?

Tags: shortcut-keys, mouse, customization, 12.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I assign actions to all my mouse buttons?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19569/how-can-i-assign-actions-to-all-my-mouse-buttons)
>   [What are some of the issues with ccsm and why should I not use it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80589/what-are-some-of-the-issues-with-ccsm-and-why-should-i-not-use-it)

I want mouse button 9 to run `/usr/bin/chromium-browser`.

[image: Logitech Marathon Mouse M705 - Ubuntu button mapping]

How can I make this happen?

Comment: @BrunoPereira Ah, with the repeated mentions of driver hunting and button detection I initially misinterpreted [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/19569/how-can-i-assign-actions-to-all-my-mouse-buttons) as being *only* about detecting mouse buttons on a lower level. Can penreturn's answer be merged in? Out of the three solutions posted, it's the only one that's available in Ubuntu 12.10.