# Configure buttons on Logitech M705

Tags: 12.04, input-devices, logitech, button, xinput

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I assign actions to all my mouse buttons?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19569/how-can-i-assign-actions-to-all-my-mouse-buttons)

I would like change the extra button functionality. I want change the Back/Forward button to Sound up/Sound down.

It is possible in Ubuntu? I had been searching, but I haven't found any relevant results.

Comment: Have you tried IMWheel from the software centre?

Comment: Also, see [this](http://askubuntu.com/q/195265/1859) for a mapping of button numbers on that mouse, and [this](http://askubuntu.com/q/214728/1859) for volume up/down commands.