# How can I access the configuration window for Easystroke Gesture Recognition?

Tags: configuration, gestures

When I run [Easystroke Gesture Recognition](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/easystroke/), nothing happens!

How can I access its configuration window so I can start using it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few options:

## Open it from the Dash again

If you open Easystroke Gesture Recognition while it's already running, it will show the configuration window instead of starting a duplicate instance.

[image: Unity Dash icon for Easystroke Gesture Recognition]

## Define a gesture

Once you've gotten the configuration window open, you can create an action for easy access in the future. Set the type to **Misc**, and the details to **Show/Hide**.

[image: Easystroke Gesture Recognition - Actions - Show/Hide Configuration]

## Use the command line

The following command will cause Easystroke to immediately open the configuration window:

```
easystroke --show-gui
```

## Enable the tray icon

Easystroke uses an old, unsupported method for displaying its notification icon. As a workaround until Easystroke fixed, you can grant it an exception by adding `easystroke` to the [system tray white list](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30742/how-do-i-access-and-enable-more-icons-to-be-in-the-system-tray).

[image: Tray icon for Easystroke Gesture Recognition in Unity on Ubuntu 12.10]