# How do I disable the fourth button on an Apple Mighty Mouse?

Tags: firefox, mouse, apple

I have an Apple Mighty Mouse, but it's been banged up a bit. The side buttons (4th buttons) are way too easily pressed. When I'm using Firefox, the 4th button can accidentally click and I'd go back one page, which can be really aggravating. How can I disable the 4th button (on either Firefox or Ubuntu) without getting any new hardware?

Comment: You could also assign the key to a null command.  See http://askubuntu.com/a/308969/8844

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those buttons (forward and back) drive me crazy too! Here's what worked for me:

Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> by default),  and run:

```
$ xev | grep -A2 ButtonPress
```

This will pop open a window. Move the mouse into that window, and press the button(s) that you wish to disable. Look at the third line for each button-press, which will look something like:

```
ButtonPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4000001,
    root 0x2f2, subw 0x0, time 355888399, (114,122), root:(114,174),
    state 0x10, button 8, same_screen YES
```

Note the number after `button`. For me, the back/forward buttons were numbers 8 and 9.
Close the `xev` window, and create/edit an `.Xmodmap` file in your home directory:

```
$ cat >> ~/.Xmodmap
! Disable buttons 8 and 9
pointer = 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 0 0
```

In your case, to just disable button 4, you'd want `pointer = 1 2 3 0 5 6 7 8 9`.
 Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> to return to the prompt, then test it out:

```
$ xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
```

This will load the `.Xmodmap` file and your button(s) should be disabled immediately.

Most desktop environments should load this file automatically next time you log in, making the change permanent.

This is an old question, but I hope this answer helps someone.

Answer (score -1):

its simple. just follow these steps:

1. Go into system settings found in your dock or by searching after pressing Alt-F2
2. Go into "mouse and touchpad" (or something similar, thats just what it says for me)
3. Go change the setting you want

Comment: When posting an answer it's always good practice to go through the steps your posting, so you can verify it works! If you had done so you'd see there is no option in Mouse and Touchpad settings for changing the function of extra mouse buttons.

Comment: i did, i havent done it with his/her specific model, but it did in fact work

Comment: Ah, sorry! I realise now that as I'm using a laptop it only gives me touchpad specific options which don't include any settings for extra buttons. :)