# Where can I find btnx?

Tags: mouse, services, button

I'm having trouble finding packages or source for the btnx service, it looks like the ollisalonen.com site that hosted btnx is no longer available. I also cannot find any btnx packages in apt or on the Ubuntu software center.

Does anyone know how to get btnx these days?