# Problem with remapping graphics tablet buttons to keyboard shortcuts

Tags: shortcut-keys, mouse, xbindkeys

I have a cheap xp-pen tablet with 8 extra buttons. I'd like to map them to keyboard shortcuts, such as Ctrl-Z, to use with Krita/Gimp/etc, but vendor's [utility](https://www.xp-pen.ru/download-119.html) more looks as a proof-of-concept.

I also tried to use a EasyStroke as proposed [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/195280/640378), but uh.

The pad recognized by xinput as a mouse with 12 buttons. My plan was:

- remap tablet buttons to 100-107 as described [there](https://askubuntu.com/a/689069/640378)
- capture events by xbindkeys
- determinate current profile based on active window
- simulate keystrokes by xev or xdotool
- [extra] activate/deactivate this bicycle by udev rules or smth like

Everything works fine with simple cases, such as typing key number, but more complicated ones fails with "sticking" keys.

I uploaded my work into git [repo](https://bitbucket.org/sleeply4cat/xp-pen-keybinder/src/master/). Default profile works fine with xdotool and xte variants, krita and gimp profiles doesn't work in both cases.

I logged events in handler.sh and discovered that xbindkeys "looses" some release events after krita or gimp profile execution, but works nice after default. I thought that this might be due to the execution of the handler for too long, and started it in a separate process, but this didn't change anything.

Well.. What could be the cause of this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause is pretty simple: according to gimp's profile, xev press control/shift buttons, and xbindkeys skips release event because shift is still pressed. You can duplicate each section of config to handle such situations, like this:

```
"/opt/xp-pen/handler.sh 1 1"
  b:100
"/opt/xp-pen/handler.sh 1 1"
  b:100 + shift
"/opt/xp-pen/handler.sh 1 1"
  b:100 + control
...
```