# How can I remap my mouse buttons in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: mouse

My touchpad recently went out and I need to remap my mouse to function how I want it to. In windows, I use X-Mouse Button Control which works perfectly. Is there a similar program for Ubuntu that does this as well? It doesn't matter if it's GUI based or terminal based, just so long as these settings will be activated on startup.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: This may be useful for  you: http://askubuntu.com/a/492745/57576