# A4Tech 6100F Wireless Mouse Button Besides Scroll Not working

Tags: mouse, button

My mouse is a relative new model... the indicated button however serves no functionality; whereas I want say a double click with the button besides scroll

[image]

I have so far visited following URLs

1] https://askubuntu.com/a/492745/110979

2] https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/map-mouse-on-linux/

Using `xev` or `xinput test` it is shown that I have following configuration

Button---Functionality

1---Left click

2---Middle(scroll) click

3---Right click

4---Scroll up

5---Scroll down

neither command register my click on the middle (yellow arrowed) button. Before I start Mapping Mouse Buttons I have to make sure every button registers a click, so how I do that ..is there another command utility

Comment: That additional button is usually to toggle resolutions (displacement speed) and cannot be mapped to other functions because it doesn't send any signal out.

Comment: I am afraid that isn't the case ..its more like a programmable button. I have found strikingly similar problem here  http://superuser.com/questions/424240/use-the-programmable-button-of-an-a4tech-mouse-in-linux