# Using Gaming Software trough WINE

Tags: drivers, usb, keyboard, wine, mouse

So recently I bought a new mouse and it's pretty useless, without it's "drivers". It does work, but I can't install macros or remap the additional buttons. So the "drivers" are only for Windows XP and newer ( 32 bit or 64 bit ). And I wouldn't really care, my keyboard also has an application for adjusting settings and recording macros. The solution that I know works is trough VB ( Virtual Box ), but it's not a good solution and it`s very hard to pull off, because every time I switch a setting I have to reboot my laptop, because giving Windows access to the USB directly it steals my cursor and there is no shortcut to get it back, so I have to reboot. I started to look for a solution using WINE, both the "drivers" don't recognise my connected USB devices, so then I read that WINE doesn't support USB devices, and I must add it as a drive by using:

```
winecfg-deveopment
```

This didn't work for me, because I don't know the mounting point of my mouse / keyboard and after using:

```
dmesg
```

Then I saw my keyboard as input10, and my mouse as input0. But this did not work. I also read that there is some USB patch, but then I have to compile WINE myself, which I don't have a problem with, but the wiki.winehq.org/USB was empty. So I can't find the USB patch. The other method was using by using /dev/ttyUSB*, but I don't have such files, although my mouse is connected, there were two folders named usb, and one named bus. They all have some strange contents, which I don't know how to deal with. Another solution that I tried is is using symbolic links in `~/.wine/dosdevices` to a few of these strange files and naming them like com ports but for this the program must support using com ports which i don't know if it does. In their wiki says that this is the way for versions "prior to 2.8" and for my version I must edit the registry HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wine and the I should have a Ports entry, but I don't. If I'm supposted to do it myself than can you please help me.I also downloaded winetricks, but it says that it fails to open the GUI and closes itself.

---

My system: Acer Aspire S3 ultra book, running Ubuntu 17.04, with Gnome

My WINE: latest development release: 2.8

My mouse and keyboard: Trust GXT 158 and ThermalTake Challenger Pro

---

Articles that I were reading regarding the subject:

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/how-to-use-usb-devices-a-webcam-in-this-case-in-wine-1-3-16-a-873968/

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1335098

https://wiki.winehq.org/Wine_User%27s_Guide#Drive_Settings ( The Drive Settings article 4.1.4 )

Thanks in advance :)
Also I'd prefer not to use VMs, but WINE.

Comment: "Also I'd prefer not to use VMs, but WINE." I d. not consider this a smart choice. Wine is crap. Always has. Always will be. The only way for Wine to work is if Microsoft makes a version. The only good options for playing windows games is through dual boot or a VM.

Comment: @Rinzwind dual booting ? -no,because i have to install windows 10 then reinstall Ubuntu and everything else or backup 500 GB of data somewhere. I'd also not like to pay and I don't like the Windows Privacy issues also if you'd suggest a cracked Windows, no

Comment: @Rinzwind VM, no because I only have about 3,7 GiB of RAM and also having a VM is too much for this laptop. Also the solution that I found requires a reboot for even the smallest tweak.

Comment: I definitely wouldn't suggest using Wine to run mouse drivers. If you want to remap buttons, look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/492744/how-do-i-automatically-remap-buttons-on-my-mouse-at-startup If you want to record macros, look into xmacro or cnee