# Natural scrolling in 18.04 system-wide?

Tags: mouse, xfce

This is about getting 'natural scrolling' aka 'inverted scrolling' to work with ALL applications system-wide with USB mice and trackpoints.
This issue is driving me nuts since 12.04 where I fianlly got it working with a bunch of workarounds.

I'm using **Ubuntu Studio 18.04 (xfce 4.12 desktop)** and there's a 'Natural Scrolling' option in Preferences. It works as expected in browser and file manager, and also in text editors etc. However, i.e. in xfce4-terminal and mousepad (text editor) and some other apps it's still 'unnatural scrolling'

Anyone knows what's the development status on this topic?
Am I missing something?

Any help is appreciated before I'll start over and test all those workarounds.

Ubuntu Studio 18.04.1 with xfce 4.12
4.15.0-20-lowlatency #21-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT

Answer (score 3):

IIRC the inconsistent 'reversed scrolling' behaviour even across the default (x)ubuntu apps was due to the different scroll handling in GTK2 and GTK3. Don't know if that still applies..

Anyway, I just found out the "old xinput trick" still works (xUbuntu 18.04.1, xinput version 1.6.2), so I might as well share how it works. And how to make it persist reboots.

**Test / temporary solution**

List all your currently available pointers and keyboards:

`xinput list`

Something like this will appear:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Laser Mouse                  id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint                     id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                    id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Pick the `id` of the pointer in question, list all its device properties:

`xinput list-props 12`

```
Device 'TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint':
    Device Enabled (143):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (145): 1.000000, ...
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (281):   1
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (282):   0
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (283):    0, 0, 1
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (284):   0, 0, 1
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (285):   0, 0, 1
    libinput Button Scrolling Button (286): 2
    ...
```

This is what we need: `libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (281)`

To enable natural scrolling globally i.e. for "TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint" (for the current session), first turn it OFF in 'Mouse & Touchpad' preferences.
Enter one of those two lines below, hit Enter. (both do the same, because to read or write a property you can use either its entire(!) name or its ID)

`xinput set-prop 12 "libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled" 1`

`xinput set-prop 12 "281" 1`

Now test it in applications where naturalscroling wouldn't work via system preferences.

**Permanent solution**

If the above test worked on your machine, you can apply the changes everytime you log into your session with a small startup script. The script part that matches `deviceName` is from [this answer about button maps](https://askubuntu.com/a/492745/224347) by @zerobandwidth).

Save the code below as `natural_scrolling.sh` in your home directory or in `/any/path/youLike`

```
#!/bin/bash
# Find all xinput devices whose name matches any of the arguments passed here,
# then set the Natural Scrolling' property to '1' regardless of its
# current state.

# expect multiple arguments, store them as array
deviceNames="$@"

# exit if no argument is passed
if [ "$deviceNames" = "" ]; then
        echo "No argument received, exiting."
        echo "Call this script with argument(s) like 'Logitech' that match"
        echo "any of your attached pointer devices."
    exit 1
fi

for deviceName in $deviceNames
do
    deviceId=$(xinput --list | awk -v search="$deviceName" \
    '$0 ~ search {match($0, /id=[0-9]+/);\
                  if (RSTART) \
                    print substr($0, RSTART+3, RLENGTH-3)\
                 }'\
     )
  # set device-specific property (works i.e for 'TrackPoint' & 'Logitech')
  xinput set-prop $deviceId "libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled" 1
done
```

Mark the script executable:

`chmod +x natural_scrolling.sh`

Call it with unique(!) `device_name` string(s) as argument:

`/any/path/youLike/natural_scrolling.sh Logitech TrackPoint`

Add it to your startup applications, i.e via Session & Startup preferences in xfce and test it by logging out & back in again.

Answer (score 2):

Alas, I don't have enough reputation to comment, so I'm going to have to add this as an answer. For anyone stumbling upon this, there's a very small error in the code above. The penultimate line:

```
xinput set-prop $id "libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled" 1
```

Should read:

```
xinput set-prop $deviceId "libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled" 1
```

Also, I use a Logitech Ultrathin Mouse and for who-knows-what reason, it connects both as a mouse and keyboard, and therefore appears twice in `xinput list`. I therefore added piping the output to `head -1` to limit what gets returned to just the first entry (which in my case is always the mouse):

```
...
                    print substr($0, RSTART+3, RLENGTH-3)\
                 }' | head -1 \
     )
...
```