# How to map a single click into a double-click?

Tags: mouse, xinput, doubleclick

I have a multi-button mouse.  I can change the order of the buttons, for example so the left swaps with the right, using:

```
xinput set-button-map "Mouse Name" 3 2 1 4
```

When I press the 4th button *once*, I want it to be interpreted as a *double* click on the left button.

What's the modern way to achieve that?

Comment: not an answer, rather an alternative way to choose whether mouse click is felt as a single our double dlick ... Files -> Preference -> Behavior ->  Open Action ... here it gives you options of single or double click ....  this is how I give it `Single` click so I do not have to double click anywhere

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/492744/how-do-i-automatically-remap-buttons-on-my-mouse-at-startup includes how to map single click to double click