# How to mimic Menu key using xte?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, mouse, xte

My laptop is woefully missing the Menu key, but I have some extra buttons on my mouse so I hoped to map one of them to the missing Menu key - as explained in several answers on AskUbuntu, [for example this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19569/how-can-i-assign-actions-to-all-my-mouse-buttons/308969#308969).

But unfortunately I couldn't figure out how to get `xte` to output the Menu key. I tried

```
"xte 'key Menu'"
  b:11
```

But that doesn't do anything.

I've read some examples that use `SHIFT+F10` but that doesn't really solve my problem, mainly because some applications (I'm looking at you Dolphin) don't support mimicking the Menu key using `SHIfT+10`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding sleep command. For example,
to map PrintScreen to MenuKey, put this in `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/sxhkd/sxhkdrc`:

```
Print
    sleep 0.1 && xte "key Menu"
```

Comment: Thanks, but I've just permanently moved to Wayland a couple of months ago  Also, the laptop I got in 2016 - and still use - does have a menu key... 

Comment: You know what.. I'm just going to accept it on faith ✌️