# Completely disabling middle clicks on a buttonless touchpad in 16.04

Tags: touchpad, thinkpad

I have a Thinkpad X1 with a buttonless touchpad. If I click at the top center of the touchpad, I get a middle click. How do I disable this? I want clicking to cause a right-click on 100% of the touchpad.

Comment: On `settings` > `mouse & touchpad` did you select `primary button` to be Right click?

Comment: Yes, and I do get a right-click at 95% of the trackpad. Only in the top middle, clicking triggers a middle-mouseclick instead.

Comment: Found this, maybe it can help you http://askubuntu.com/questions/19569/how-can-i-assign-actions-to-all-my-mouse-buttons#308969