# Full personalization of all the mouse buttons

Tags: 14.04, mouse

I'm starting to use Ubuntu after living with windows my entire life, and there's one thing that I miss from windows: the ability to transform my mouse in a full user experience interface with XMouseButtonControl.

I already found plenty of programs for Ubuntu that allows me to change one key or two, but they are never as complete as XMBC for Windows.

I want a program that recognize all my mouse buttons (Left, Right, Middle, ScrollUp, ScrollDown, ScrollLeft, ScrollRight, ThumbLeft, ThumbRight), and also assign behaviours based in certain conditions, like changing the function of the left button when CTRL is down, or ThumbLeft is pressed.

All this I can do in Windows, I would like to do the same in Ubuntu, what program can I use?

Comment: looked at he solutions offered here https://askubuntu.com/questions/19569/how-can-i-assign-actions-to-all-my-mouse-buttons?

Comment: Yes, btnx is not around anymore, xev doesn't support conditional keys, easystroke doesn't recognize my tilt-wheel buttons, compizconfig is more focused on windows management, EGR is more focused on mouse getures.